# how to list a directory with _popen even though the path has a blank?

Tags: c++, windows, popen

This is my code on visual c++:

```
char dir[MAX_PATH]="";

sprintf(dir,"dir %s",cur_dir);//

FILE* cmd_dir=_popen(dir,"wt");

_pclose(cmd_dir);
```

If I tried to set `cur_dir` to `"c:\"` or `"c:\perl64"`that doesn't have a blank, it works and it will list the files in the directory.

However, if `cur_dir` is `c:\program files`, it doesn't work. Even if I open command.exe (windows terminal) and enter `dir c:\program files` it still doesn't work.

please give me some advice.

Comment: `sprintf(dir,"dir \"%s\"",cur_dir);`?

Comment: Why use _popen() at all? There are APIs for this.

Comment: I know there are so many ways to solve this problem.
But, It will be helpful later for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap your argument to `dir` in quotes, otherwise the underlying shell will treat the space as an argument separator.

```
sprintf (dir, "dir \"%s\"", cur_dir);
```

---

Currently `"dir %s"` will expand to `dir c:\program files`, which is treated as if you'd have `dir "c:\program" "files"`; ie. two arguments, instead of one.

If you open up *cmd* and write the below you should see the files in the directory of your choice:

```
cmd "c:\program files"
```

---

<sup>**Note**: be careful when you use `sprintf`, if `cur_dir` is long enough you risk of writing outside the bounds of `dir[MAX_PATH]`. Instead consider using the much safer `snprintf` which requires you to specify the maximum length of contents: `snprintf (dir, MAX_PATH, "dir \"%s\"", cur_dir);`</sup>

<sup>**Note**: This question is tagged `[c++]`, but your snippet shows no sign of C++ - it looks like C. The "*C++ way of doing it*" would include using a `std::string` to build your command, and call `_popen` with `_popen (your_string.c_str (), "wt")`.</sup>

Comment: @user1829967 Welcome to Stackoverflow, please mark this answer as *Accepted* to mark the thread as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the path in quotes "".

```
sprintf(dir,"dir \"%s\"",cur_dir);
```